# How to send a synchronized signal among three processes in C

Tags: c

I have to send signal p1 -> p2 -> p3 ->p1 ... in order to change the value of shared file. however p3 -> p1 is not working(p1 doesn't catch the signal). I put sleep to make time difference between each transition but idk what's wrong.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
void sig_usr (int signo)
{
        printf("%d\n",getpid());
//      longjmp(jumpbuffer,1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        signal(SIGUSR1, sig_usr);
        jmp_buf jumpbuffer;
        pid_t next,ppid,granmaduh;
        granmaduh = getpid();
        if ((next = fork()) <0 )
        { 
                        fprintf(stderr, "fork() error");
                        exit(1);
         }
        else if (next == 0  )
        {

                next = fork();
                if (next >0)
                {

                        sleep(6);
                }
                else 
                {
                        next = granmaduh;       
                        sleep(10);
                }
        }
        sleep(2);
        printf("%d\n",next);
        //setjmp(jumpbuffer);


        kill(next, SIGUSR1);
        exit(1);
}
```

Comment: p2 is p1's child and p3 is p2's child but no connection between p1 and p3...  that's your problem with this implementation

Comment: no i added p3's next as p1's pid.(next=granmaduh) so when p3 is about to send signal, it will send to p1 isnt't it?

Comment: Deja-vu.  Use three named semaphores.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

static void signal_handler(int);
int i, pid1, pid2,pid3, status;

int main( int argc, char *argv[], char *env[] )
{
    int exit_status;

    if( signal( SIGUSR1, signal_handler) == SIG_ERR  )
    {
        printf("Pærent: Unable to create handler for SIGUSR1\n");
    }

    // if( signal( SIGUSR2, signal_handler) == SIG_ERR  )
    // {
    //     printf("Pærent: Unable to create handler for SIGUSR2\n");
    // }

    printf( "Parent pid = %d\n", pid1=getpid() );

    if( (pid2 = fork()) == 0 )
    {
        printf( "Child pid = %d\n", getpid() );
        //printf( "Child: %d sending parent SIGUSR1\n", getpid() ); //kill( pid1, SIGUSR1 );

         if( (pid3 = fork()) == 0 )
        {
        printf( "GranChild pid = %d\n", getpid() );
        printf( "Child: %d sending parent SIGUSR1\n", getpid() ); kill( pid2, SIGUSR1 );
        }
        for( ;; ); /* loop forever */

    }
    else
    {
        /* 
         * This waits for ANY child to die.  It doesn't matter if the child
         * dies normally or from a signal.  The satus information is then
         * stored in the status integer.
         *
         * If you want to wait on a particular process use waitpid():
         *      waitpid( childPID, &status, 0 );
         * is the common usage.
         *
         * Solaris acts weirdly when a signal is given to the parent process.
         * Therefore we place the wait() inside a while loop so that wait()
         * will not return before the child has died.
         */
         /*   while( (wait( &status ) == -1) && (errno == EINTR) ) {} */

        wait(&status);

        /*
         * The information in status is *NOT* the return code!!  To make use
         * of the information we must macros to extract the needed
         * information.
         */

        /* WIFEXITED() determines if the process exited normally (returned a
         * number).  This can be done through a return or exit()
         */

        if( WIFEXITED( status ) )
        {
            /* 
             * Now we know the process exited properly so we can get the
             * return value
             *
             * Note that WEXITSTATUS only retuns the lower 8 bits!  That means
             * that if we ever expect a negative number then we have to count
             * the 8th bit as a sign bit.
             */

            exit_status = WEXITSTATUS( status );

            /* 
             * Since we expect negative numbers...
             *
             * If the exit_status is greater than 2^7 (128), thæn the eigth bit
             * is a 1, so we subtract 2^8 (256) from it to make it look like 
             * a negative number.
             */
            if( exit_status > 128 )
            {
                exit_status -= 256;
            }

            printf( "Child return - %d\n", WEXITSTATUS( status ) );
        }
        else
        {
            /* Well it didn't exit properly.  Was it a signal? */
            if( WIFSIGNALED( status ) )
            {
                /* 
                 * Yes. A signal killed the child process.  Now we can extract
                 * the signal information from status
                 */

                printf( "Child died on signal - %d\n", WTERMSIG( status ));
            }
        }

        /* 
         * There are two other macros most UNIXes use.  They are:
         *  WIFSTOPPED() and WSTOPSIG().  See the man pages on the dells for
         *  more information.
         *
         *  To wait on a particular pid - see waitpid()
         */
    }

    return 0;
}

static void signal_handler(int signo)
{

    /* signo contains the signal number that was received */
    switch( signo )
    {
        /* Signal is a SIGUSR1 */
        case SIGUSR1:
            printf( "Process %d: received SIGUSR1 \n", getpid() );
            if(pid1==getpid()) /* it is the parent */
            {
                  printf( "Process %d is passing SIGUSR1 to %d...\n", getpid(),pid2 );
                  kill( pid2, SIGUSR1 );
            }
            else if(pid2==getpid()) /* it is the child */
            {
                    printf( "Process %d is passing SIGUSR2 to itself...\n", getpid());
                    kill(getpid(), SIGUSR2);
            }
            else
            {
              printf( "Process %d is passing SIGUSR2 to itself...\n", getpid());
                    kill(pid3, SIGUSR2);
            }

            break;

        /*  It's a SIGUSR2 */
        case SIGUSR2:
            printf( "Process %d: received SIGUSR2 \n", getpid() );
            if(pid1==getpid())
            {
                  printf( "Process %d is passing SIGUSR2 to %d...\n", getpid(),pid2 );
                  kill( pid2, SIGUSR2 );
            }
            else if(pid2==getpid())/* it is the child */
            {
                     printf( "Process %d is passing SIGUSR2 to %d...\n", getpid(),pid3 );
                    kill(pid3, SIGINT);
            }
            else /* it is the child */
            {
                     printf( "Process %d is passing SIGUSR2 to %d...\n", getpid() );
                    kill(getpid(), SIGINT);
            }
            break;

        default:
                break;
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: It's an infrastructure 3 inter process communication - hope you can continue from here